# Bare-bones linux?

Tags: bash, debian, python, aptitude

I am working on a homemade OS and I was originally going to write it myself in Assembly and Python, but I decided that doing this would just be easier, faster, and more Linux-y. I have the Python part done, I just need to do the Linux part. So, I was wondering if you had any idea of a place I could get a pre-made ISO of any (preferably Debian based) Linux distro, with BASH, Aptitude, Python 2.7.6, and crontab installed, and with NO xorg or xvesa or whatever. It would also be extremely helpful if instead of posting links to places without a proper explanation and what-not, if you could just give me a download link.

Comment: Linux from scratch?

Comment: You can do a minimal install of Debian, AFAIU.

Comment: Thank you orion and vonbrand, I think i'll try debian mini-install.

Answer (score 2):

For the base distro, you can get a Debian minimal install from https://www.debian.org/CD/netinst/, during installation, do not choose any extra packages to install. After you have it installed, simply log in as root and run `apt-get install python cron`, and you that should install both, although if you want a gui for it you will  since it already has bash.